# Server port scan detector

Tags: linux, security, port

For Linux, what is the best program/daemon out there that would detect, block, and report computers scanning the server's ports, sequentially or randomly, for SSH, MySQL, popular web-based administering systems, and other security-sensible services that were moved from their default ports?

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SF (and, I'm told, other SE sites); sorry.

Comment: yeah [this is true](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1296/where-is-an-appropriate-place-to-ask-for-server-oriented-product-recommendations). But to answer the question in a general way, there are many programs out there that are run onto of iptables and will add blocked ip into ip iptables. [smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org) or [csf](http://configserver.com/index.html) are many out there. I personally use CSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigServer Services is a set perl modules/Scripts/daemons, which effectively provide you with port scanning ability, detect it, report and and block it with number of ways to tweak its options.

http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html

I personally recommend it for small scale servers.